# Deleting text in terminal with custom funcitons

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, customization, ubuntu-10.04

When in terminal I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to delete a whole word or IP (`.` is separator for each octet) when going leftward of prompt. However, if I try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to go rightward of prompt, terminal recognizes "." in IP for a separator and deletes only one chunk, until the `.` out of the whole IP.

How can I adjust that so terminal recognizes only blank spaces for separator of word or even better to have another shortcut for different separators: `.`, `=`, `,`, etc?

It is very similar with maneuvering  in terminal with Ctrl+Arrows (left and right) and behavior is similar based on what is set for word separator.

I read that Emacs editor sits behind what terminal uses to have those shortcuts but I could not get to twink it.

I'm trying to accomplish this in Ubuntu 10.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577433/deleting-input-forward-to-the-next-space) is what I was suggested in the other forum for Ubuntu 14.
Also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182855/deleting-input-forward-to-the-next-space?noredirect=1#comment304877_182855).

I tried this:

"So, now, if you want to combine those two keystrokes (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>) in a new one, you will need to bind a new keystroke (in my example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>) to execute the previous keystrokes as follow:

```
bind '"\eq": "\ew \C-w"'
```

Finally, to make these changes permanently, all you have to do is to add the following lines to your `~/.inputrc` file (if you don't have it, then create it):

```
"\ew": vi-forward-bigword
"\eq": "\ew \C-w"
```

but I get this as result:

When added that, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> still does not work, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> error does not work any more. Terminal outputs `;5D` and `;5C` when those are used to move from word to word...

Please advise what is the difference between the two versions.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone can help with this?